# Turn off xml header output in Saxon

Tags: xml, xpath, saxon

Using the .NET version of Saxon 9.4, I run a command line like:

```
Query.exe -s:myfile.xml -qs:/cruisecontrol/build/msbuild[@success='true']/project[1]/target[@name='GetLatestSource']/message[last()]/text()
```

and I get a result like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>375
```

How can I turn off the XML header (omit the XML declaration) so that I just get `375` as output?  I've checked [the documentation](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/using-xquery/commandline.xml), but perhaps I'm just missing it.

Comment: If using `saxon-js` (JS/Node) via `saxon.serialize(saxon.transform(..))` (with just a SEF), you can extract the output parameters from the SEF itself and pass them as the second parameter of `serialize()` (otherwise the serializer will not know/honor the desired output config, `omit-xml-declaration` etc.):

`let outConf = sef.C.find(c => c.N === "output")
 .C.filter(c => c.N === "property").reduce((params, c) => {
  params[c.name] = c.value === "yes" ? true : c.value === "no" ? false : c.value;
  return params;
}, {});
let result = saxon.serialize(saxon.transform(..), outConf);`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Figured it out...

I needed to add the `omit-xml-declaration` option:

```
Query.exe -s:myfile.xml -qs:"declare option saxon:output 'omit-xml-declaration=yes'; /cruisecontrol/build/msbuild[@success='true']/project[1]/target[@name='GetLatestSource']/message[last()]/text()"
```

would be one way to accomplish this.

Comment: You can also set serialization parameters directly from the command line, e.g. !method=text (this isnt quite the same as omit-xml-declaration, it also prevents < and & being escaped)

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9320462/turn-off-xml-header-output-in-saxon#comment11766283_9320707) from [Michael Kay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/415448/michael-kay), you can also use a command line parameter.

Below is the command using Java:

```
java -cp saxon9he.jar net.sf.saxon.Transform -s:mytemplate.xsl -xsl:myfile.xml !method=text
```

From the command line help:

> Saxon-HE 9.8.0.11J from Saxonica
>   Usage: see http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!using-xsl/commandline
>   Format: net.sf.saxon.Transform options params
>   Options available: -? -a -catalog -config -cr -diag -dtd -ea -expand -explain -export -ext -im -init -it -jit -l -lib -license -m -nogo -now -o -opt -or -outval -p -quit -r -relocate -repeat -s -sa -scmin -strip -t -T -target -TB -threads -TJ -Tlevel -Tout -TP -traceout -tree -u -val -versionmsg -warnings -x -xi -xmlversion -xsd -xsdversion -xsiloc -xsl -y
>   Use -XYZ:? for details of option XYZ
>   Params:
>
> ```
>  param=value           Set stylesheet string parameter
>  +param=filename       Set stylesheet document parameter
>  ?param=expression     Set stylesheet parameter using XPath
>  !param=value          Set serialization parameter
> ```

Comment: If executing from bash you will need to escape the exclamation point: `\!method=text`